# How to Fit New Classes to SKLearn Algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am in need of a SKLearn Classifier which can be trained periodically by fitting new data to the already trained algorithm while retaining the classes it has learned to fit to previously.

I have tried using warm_start on LogisticRegression and RandomForestClassifier but can't seem to figure out the configuration needed to retain the classes from the previous fitting.  Using a retraining python tool I have developed, a previously saved sklearn algorithm can be loaded using the pickle module and fit to.

```py
#Train File:

algorithm = LogisticRegression(warm_start=True)

#Fit Data, (X,y) is (100,2008),(100,) No y value is the same 
algorithm.fit(X,y)

print(len(algorithm.classes_)) #Expected 100

#Save Trained Object
with open("logreg.alg", "wb") as f:
   pickle.dump(algorithm,f)


#Re-train File:

#Load Trained Object
with open("logreg.alg", "rb") as f:
   algorithm = pickle.load(f)

#Fit New Data, (X,y) again is (100,2008),(100,) No y value has been trained before or is the same
algorithm.fit(X,y)

print(len(algorithm.classes_)) #Expected 200, Actual 100

#Save Trained Object
with open("logreg.alg", "wb") as f:
   pickle.dump(algorithm,f)
```

I am expecting the number of classes to increase after each re-fitting, but it seems the algorithm resets its values after each run.  For example, the first fitting should have set classes "0" through "99", now I want to fit again with classes "100" through "199" to have a trained algorithm of classes from "0" though "199".

Am I doing something wrong or misinterpreting the "warm_start" parameter?  I would love to use Logistic Regression but am open to other Classifiers.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: are you sure *unique values* of second batch of `y` doesn't overlap with first one? try removing the `len` and just do `print(algorithm.classes_)`.

Comment: @ShihabShahriarKhan I'm positive they do not overlap. I am basically trying to correlate each X to its own unique y.  Printing out the classes_ shows only the 100 y values from refitting and nothing from the first fitting